# How to present a paper via skype?

Tags: presentation, video-conference

I'm doing a skype presentation of a paper that would be published soon. The presentation is for an improvement of a procedure that was not so accurate before (Computer Science related). Should I only keep the cam towards me or should I share the screen as well with the ppts? I've got 7 minutes for the presentation and 3 minutes for Q & A. It's my first skype presentation and I have no idea on how this would be done.

Comment: It is practically impossible to recommend you anything feasible without knowing: 1) your field; 2) nature of the paper (i.e., what kind of content it contains); 3) the goal of the presentation; 4) your audience; 5) whether Skype actually has this functionality (I am not aware of it and I use Skype for many years).

Comment: Clarification: I know that one can share screen in Skype, but IMHO it lacks other relevant features, such as using pointer of specific shape, etc.

Comment: My field is Computer science, the paper describes a new improvement in a data analytics method. The goal of my presentation would be to describe what I've done to improve the current method in my paper. Skype does provide the functionality. I should use the screen share to show them the slides as I explain it, right?

Comment: I see. Sure, Skype allows to share screen. You have read my clarification above, right? What I meant by "functionality" is something more than just that. For example, if you want to emphasize particular part of your screen/slide or point to some areas, it would be handy to have some visual aid for that (such as in many screencast tools). So, if you don't need this functionality, you're all set: https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10215/how-do-i-share-my-screen-in-skype-for-windows-desktop. Of course, for emphasizing an area on your slides, you can use presentation SW's functionality. Good luck!

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh Thanks a lot. I understand the need to point out a particular part on the screen. I would not need it but I will look into it to make the presentation better.

Comment: You're very welcome! For presentations, especially in CS and similar fields, I highly recommend to use _LaTeX_ with _Beamer_ package (perhaps, you're using them already).

Comment: I don't think this question deserves the downvotes. It might help to add an opening sentence setting the scene for the main question: what is the presentation for, who are the audience, why does it have to be over skype, ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have presented powerpoint slides by:

1. voice call while screen sharing the window with the presentation (works quite well)
2. video call with slides behind me, having emailed the slides to the audience beforehand (works well for smaller audiences as long as you remember to say "next slide" or similar when you change. Sounds like it would be annoying but everyone gets used to it very quickly).

I have also seen

3. record the presentation offline, replay as a video and have a skype q&a afterwards (this was odd, I wouldn't recommend it).

Final tips:

- Do a practice run with your supervisor/colleague over Skype
- Make sure you have reliable, fast internet (at my University that still means a wire) and a quiet room

Comment: Thanks a lot. That pretty much gives me every detail I need to work with.